# Разбор кода ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java

При изучении исходного кода наткнулся на следующий отрывок:

```
#JDK 8, java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor 1120:1137

final void runWorker(Worker w) {
    Thread wt = Thread.currentThread();
    Runnable task = w.firstTask;
    w.firstTask = null;
    w.unlock(); // allow interrupts
    boolean completedAbruptly = true;
    try {
        while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
            w.lock();
            // If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
            // if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
            // requires a recheck in second case to deal with
            // shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
            if ((runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP) ||
                 (Thread.interrupted() &&
                  runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP))) &&
                !wt.isInterrupted())
                wt.interrupt();
```

Насколько понимаю, вместо `Thread.interrupted()` стоило вызвать `wt.interrupted()` - просто из соображений единообразности кода (само выполнение бы это не поменяло). Прав ли я, или это какая-то фича, которую я недоглядел?

upd. в первичной редакции - оставлена неизменной выше - я допустил ошибку на замыленную голову, альтернативой является вызов `wt.isInterrupted(true)`

Comment: `Thread.interrupted()` - статический метод. Статические методы непринято вызывать на экземпляре класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конкретно вашем случае разницы не будет, т. к. `wt` и есть текущий поток. Но чтобы не заставлять читателя думать «а является ли `wt` текущим потоком?», лучше вызывать статический метод статическим образом.

---

Пояснение:

Как уже правильно отмечено, `interrupted` — статический метод, который вызывается на текущем потоке.

Если у вас `t` — `Thread`, не являющийся текущим, и вы вызываете `t.interrupted()`, то вызовется статический метод, который, разумеется, сообщит вам состояние флага прерывания потока не для `t`, а для текущего потока! Это может привести к достаточно неприятным ошибкам.

Comment: Вот меня и напрягает, что с потоком во всех случаях, кроме одного, взаимодействуют напрямую. С потоком **уже** работают не как с текущим, зачем тогда усложнять читаемость?

Comment: @Etki: Вопрос по сути нужно адресовать к разработчикам рантайм-библиотеки. Зачем они сделали статический метод, ума не приложу. Но раз уж метод статический, вызывать его через инстанс хуже, чем нарушать читабельность. Потому что читабельность играет против интуиции в данном случае.

Comment: Статический метод на самом деле является просто оберткой над нестатическим. Но я немного накосячил с написанием альтернативного пути, вероятно, его вызывают просто потому, что альтернативный путь предполагает вызов с аргументами, и, действительно, является более приемлемым API. Проблема скорее в сигнатуре, чем в статика / не статика

Comment: @Etki: Ну. там ещё есть инстанс-метод `isInterrupted`, но он не сбрасывает внутренний флаг. А статический сбрасывает. Непонятный зоопарк почти одинаковых методов. Авторы API курили что-то недоброе.

Comment: ох, я и не заметил, что он приватный. вопрос окончательно снят.